Monomial symmetric polynomial as linear combination of power sum polynomials
I'm trying to understand the formula for $E_{\lambda\mu}$ given in proposition 2.13 of this paper (page 38).

I don't understand what is meant by $\nu^{(1)} \cup \nu^{(2)} \cup \cdots \cup \nu^{(\ell(\mu))} = \lambda$. I thought I understood, but I implemented this formula and the results are not correct. And the figures given at the next page of the paper confirm my misunderstanding:

Here $\lambda = (4, 2, 1)$. As I understand, the shapes of the tableaux correspond to all partitions $\mu$ for which $E_{\lambda\mu} \neq 0$. The digits $1$, $2$, $3$ correspond to $\nu^{(1)}$, $\nu^{(2)}$ and $\nu^{(3)}$, but this is the point I don't understand, especially for figures 3 and 6. Could you shade some light on my mind?
